# Multiple logging files

Tags: java, logging

I want to make multiple logging files (For each day), the code I have is this:

```
public class LoggingInkrement {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingInkrement.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();

        try {
            FileHandler fhandler = new FileHandler("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Logging%g.txt", 1024*1024,10, true);
            SimpleFormatter sformatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fhandler.setFormatter(sformatter);
            logger.addHandler(fhandler);

        } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        try {
          ((Object) null).toString();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            logger.log( Level.SEVERE, "oh oh", e );
        }
        logger.info( "Hat funktioniert" );
    }
}
```

my problem is that:
**First run:** `logging0.txt` is created
**Second run:** nothing happens

the changes are unnoticed **(it stays on "Hat funktioniert")** regardless of the changes i made in `logger.info`

**but my desired outcome is:**

- You can make logging files with a set size
- the files append and dont overwrite till they're full limit
- The files are automatically deleted when outdated
- logging0.txt
- logging1.txt
- logging2.txt

and so on

but I have no idea how I could do it

Comment: Instead of rolling your own wouldn't it be easier to use something like [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) or [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) which provides this out-of-the-box? That way it is a matter of simple configuration instead of rolling your own. Drawback is that you need some additional dependencies.

Comment: thats the challange, we arent allowed to use libraries and so on when it isnt truly necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileHandler doesn't support [daily file rotation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6350749).  However, you can always trigger a rotation by creating a throw away FileHandler with the limit set to zero and append set to false.

```
if (isNewDay()) { //then rotate and close.
    new FileHandler("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Logging%g.txt",0,5, false).close();
}

//Open the log file.
FileHandler fhandler = new FileHandler("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Logging%g.txt", 1024*1024,10, true);
```